# Lift from a Django developer's point of view

Tags: scala, lift

I'm currently looking at Lift - and coming from Django it seems like it is much less elegant (and more messy?).
There does not seem to be a standard "good" way of doing things in Lift. There is no MVC, nice templates, etc...

Have any django (or even rails) people tried lift - and if so, did you have any success?

Comment: Everything you don't understand looks scary the first time through.

Comment: Django didn't look scary O_o nor python :-)

Comment: Lift doesn't look like similar as any other frameworks. It's has it's own ways of doing things almost in everything, if you're not a proficient Scala user, it's gonna be rather frustrating. But I suggest you give it try first and see if it suits for you. It's gonna be more complex than django and rails.

Comment: Actually, David Pollak - the Lift creator - wrote Lift after getting frustrated with existing frameworks: http://blog.lostlake.org/index.php?/archives/16-Web-Framework-Manifesto.html. Additionally there is MVC support in Lift, he added it in less than an hour because he got annoyed by those "Lift can't do MVC" guys. http://jaxenter.com/interview-what-s-new-in-lift-2-2-33348.html

Comment: "The helper class is nothing that a skilled Lift developer couldn't write themselves in an afternoon (it took me 45 minutes)" - I don't know sounds kind of cocky to me. I mean if it's so easy to write why didn't he just do it right away?

Comment: @drozzy: Because not everyone has subscribed to the "MVC is the solution to everything" church.

Comment: I understand. But i think he is also being a little elitist by implying the everyone who does like MVC is not a "skilled" developer. In any case - maybe I am reading too much into this!!!

Answer (score 2):

It seems less elegant not because it is more messy but because it does not meet your expectations.
If you need a framework for JVM then have a look at [Play!](http://www.playframework.org/). It is much closer to what you get used to.

Comment: I don't need a JVM framework - I am just looking for a nice framework to learn that is statically typed. Also - I rather like Scala.

Comment: Then learn Lift. It will melt your brain. But please do not make an assumption that Scala==Lift.

Answer (score 1):

The view-centric approach that lift takes is very strait-forward for me though.

The only thing that I do not like about django (or any other) is it's template language. It makes me feel that I am not using python at all.